# Why in the code i ≃ n?

Tags: algorithms, notation

```
i=2;
while(i<n)
{
   write('*');
   i=i*i;
}
```

Why $n ≃ i$?

I mean suppose $n=1000$ and so $i= 2,4,16,32,256,65536$ is in every steps.

In the book wrote $2^2 power(k)$ is pattern for growing $i$ so  $n ≃ i$ and...

Now 65536 or 256 isn't equal to 1000 or around 1000.

But why  $n ≃ i$?

This chapter is about notations.

Comment: How does your source define this notation? It is impossible to answer your question without this knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\space ≃ \space$ means "*asymptotically equal to*".

So when you read $ n ≃ i$, you can read it as $n$ *asymptotically* approaches $i$.

This means that the more $n$ increase in size, the more $i$ increase in size but $n$ never become equal to $i$.

> I mean suppose $n=1000$ and so $i=2,4,16,32,256,65536$ is in every steps.

This contains an error: when the program start $i=2$. At the first cicle, $i=2^2 = 4 $. $\space$ At the second cicle, $i=4^2=16$. $\space$ At the third cicle, $i = 16^2= 256$. $\space$ At the fourth cycle, $i=256^2 = 65536$. $\space$ At the fifth cycle the program stops since $i>n$.

Comment: I think $i$ asymptotically approaches $n$ . because $i$ in every step is go on and $n$ is fixed?!(please see the code)